# How do you determine what is causing a page to load slow?

Tags: html

So I have this WordPress page just full of html and it takes like 6 seconds to load compare to the rest of the pages where they load in 1 second.

So I check firebug net tab and it simply just tells me its HTML that takes 6 seconds.  I've checked all the media like images and even checked JS and both of those items loaded in milliseconds.

My question now is if it says its HTML, what does that really mean?  How would I determine what part of the HTML is loading slow so I can fix it?

Any insights would be greatful.

Comment: If it's "just HTML', it's likely the backend PHP code that is the issue. You may want to try disabling any plugins you have installed to see if one of those is the culprit.

Comment: no plugins installed and i already check the queries for that page so that is not it either...

Comment: Well, it's highly unlikely that the HTML is simply taking a long time to transfer especially since your media seems to be loading fine. The most likely scenario is something on the backend causing a delay.

Comment: Ok I will look further.  I just thought someone knew something about the firebug HTML stats that I didn't...Or perhaps I just have too much html on one page if that is even possible...

Comment: Unless your page is really huge, that's not likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fiddler to have a more detailedd information on each of the web requests that you need to load the page, or you can even go further and use wireshark to go into much lower level to see the transmission that are happening over the wire.

By the way, usually to reduce the bandwith or time of requests, usually you can use sprites to have 1 single request of an image that has many pictures inside of it, instead of many small requests for a single minimal picture.

Comment: Thx for the input however i am developing locally so not sure if those sites you mentioned will work for me.  And as I mentioned, i checked the load times for the images and they are fine...firebug will tell you exactly what is taking the time between assets and html and assets are fine...just html that states around 6 seconds.

Comment: @Rick it doesn't matter if you are developing or not, Fiddler and Wireshark just look at the traffic, not the code. If HTML is taking more time it might be due to slow rendering when running your server code.

Comment: yeah I know what you mean, and you also have traffic inside your own machine, is a simple http protocol that happens in your local server. You know what can you do? print the datetime on the last php write, monitor with fiddler to see when did you receive the first and last web request, and compare the results. That should give you some hint at least to start looking for bugs.